# JS regex for match sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not able to create a regex for correctly match single sentences in a text with javascript. I've used `/([!?.:])\s+/g` but doesn't match a correct sentence in a long sequence.

For example

```
[1](I have received a big present!) [2](You know?)
[3](it's, really, a car.) [4](The car have: a blue color)

[5](It's very hardly to drive.)
```

Total senctences: 5
What can be a correct regex for match a sentence?

Edit:

I've numbered all the sentences. I want to match a single sentence separated by `.` or `\n\n` or `\n` or `!` etc.

Comment: what? you want a regex to match what? please try to explain again so we can help. i dont understand your problem here.

Comment: "The car have: a blue color" its an other sentence without point at end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following this**

```js
var str='this is a pen. i am a boy';
var res= str.split(/[\.\!]+\s*|\n+\s*/);  //this code return a array of sentense.
alert(res);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
I have received a big present!
You know?
it's, really, a car.
The car have: a blue color
It's very hardly to drive.

([^ \r\n][^!?\.\r\n]+[\w!?\.]+)
```

```js
var m=$("#txa")[0].defaultValue.match(/([^ \r\n][^!?\.\r\n]+[\w!?\.]+)/g);

$("<pre>"+m.join('<br/>')+"</pre>").appendTo('body')
//document.write(m.join('\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols=80 rows=7 id="txa">
  I have received a big present! You know?
it's, really, a car. The car have: a blue color 

It's very hardly to drive.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there anything it shouldn't match?

Otherwise just use /./g

It accepts everything accept a new line